# Right side of border not drawing

Tags: android, shapes

I'm drawing rectangles dynamically in my app but for some reason the right border is not appearing. The other three borders are appearing. Here is my code for the custom view:

```
private class RectView extends View{

    int leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY;
    boolean isAppt;
    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Rect rectangle;
    String time;

    public RectView(Context context, int _leftX, int _rightX, int _topY, int _bottomY,
            boolean _isAppt, String _time){
        super(context);
        leftX = _leftX;
        rightX = _rightX;
        topY = _topY;
        bottomY = _bottomY;
        isAppt = _isAppt;
        time = _time;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        rectPaint = new Paint();

        if(isAppt){
            rectPaint.setARGB(144, 217, 131, 121);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
        else{
            rectPaint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
        if(leftX > rightX || topY > bottomY)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rectangle = new Rect(leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY);

        int height = bottomY;
        int width = rightX - leftX;
        MyUtility.LogD_Common("Height = " + height + ", Width = " + width);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        params.leftMargin = leftX;
        params.rightMargin = 10;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
        if(isAppt){
            rectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
        }
    }

}
```

What is causing the right border to not display?

Comment: It's not unlikely the right edge is drawn outside of the bounds of the custom view; for example because of constraints added by setting a margin.

Comment: Would there be any way of having the constraints and still have the right edge drawn?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it displays perfect for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            this.addContentView(new RectView(this, 10, 100, 10, 100, true, "abcd"), new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

Please check your parameters:

```
new RectView(this, 10, 100, 10, 100, true, "abcd")
```

If your _righX and _bottomY are more than screen size, the right border won't be displayed in screen:

```
new RectView(this, 10, 1000, 10, 1000, true, "abcd")
```

There is a way to detect the screen size and limit the rect size:

```
int screenWidth = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int screenHeight = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

if(rightX > screenWidth)
    rightX = screenWidth;

if(bottomY > screenHeight)
    bottomY = screenHeight;

rectangle = new Rect(leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY);
```